# How to take over as Rhodecode administrator

Tags: rhodecode

Our Rhodecode adminstrator has left he company.  I have root access
to the box.

How do I give my Rhodecode account administrator privileges?

Answer (score 1):

If you can guess the mysql password, you can make your self admin with

```
mysql> use rhodecode;
mysql> update users set admin = 1 where username = 'your.username';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use recovery console of RhodeCode and reset current user password.

See here: https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/admin/reset-information.html#manually-reset-password